# how replace "duration" in Stripe in latest versions?

Tags: stripe-payments

In recent versions, 'duration' has been removed. I need to create a plan that will charge monthly and deactivate the subscription after 3 months. I seem it could have been described in 'duration'

```
recurring: {
    interval: 'month',
    interval_count: 3
  }
```

But that's not certain.

Can `cancel_at: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 60 * 24 * 90)` when creating a subscription replace this if the billing is not every 30 days but monthly regardless of the number of days in the month? If this period falls on February, the payment will be charged a fourth time in the last days of deactivation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a subscription running for a defined period of time then cancel, you can either:

1. Update the subscription to specify a `cancel_at` timestamp ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-cancel_at))
2. You can use [Subscription Schedules](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules) and define your phase to run for `iterations=3` and set the `end_behavior=cancel` similar to the "installment plan" example use case ([docs](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules/use-cases#installment-plans)).